# Device: Motorola Moto Z2 Play does not appear in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have some feedback from a device `Motorola moto z2` but it doesn't appear in Firebase Crashlytics.

I expected to find this device in crashlytics, but it's not there.

Is there some alternate device name that it might appear under?